# tail of divergent series

Tags: real-analysis

**Motivation.** [Cauchy convergence criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series#Cauchy_convergence_criterion) for real series $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty 
r_i$ is equivalent to the condition

$$
\lim\limits_{\substack{n\to\infty\\m\to\infty}}
\sum\limits_{i=n}^m 
r_i
=0
$$

with $r_i$ being real, and for all natural $n$ and $m$ such that $n<m$.

**Definition.** Define number $T$ by

$$T=\limsup\limits_{\substack{n\to\infty\\m\to\infty}} 
\left\{
\sum\limits_{i=n}^m 
r_i
\right\}_{n,m}
$$

for all natural $n$ and $m$ such that $n<m$.

Obviously, the series $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty 
r_i$ converges if and only if $T=0$.

Another obvious result is that the series $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty 
r_i$ diverges if and only if $T>0$.

**Question.** Let for the sake of simplicity $r_i>0$ for all $i$. Any properly divergent series $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty 
r_i$ I've encountered had the property $T=\infty$. I haven't encountered a single series of positive terms so far such that $0<T<\infty$.

*Is there a real series* $\sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty 
r_i$ *of strictly positive terms* $r_i$ *with property* $0<T<\infty$?

Comment: I think there is no such series. If terms are positive, a divergent series must diverge to $+ \infty$...

Comment: If the tails converge to a finite number, then by considering the difference between the tails, we see that the series is Cauchy, so the tails converge to $0$.

Comment: @saulspatz Hi. Would you care to elaborate a bit on the idea that a difference between tails points to the series being Cauchy? Do notice that tails are considered in the limit of partial sums becoming infinite series.

Comment: $\sum_{i=n}^m r_i=\sum_{i=n}^\infty r_i-\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty r_i$

Comment: @saulspatz Hi. I still fail to see how.

Comment: If the tails converge, that means the difference between two tails goes to $0$.  But the difference between two tails is just what we need to go to $0$ in order for the series to be Cauchy.  If you don't think this is true, please explicitly say why not.

Comment: @saulspatz Hi. Yes, you probably call the series $\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty r_i$ the tail. This most certainly does not converge, since $T>0$, and the series is Cauchy if and only if $T=0$. What converges is the limit of tail as $m\to\infty$, if such series even exists at all...